# What is awaitable?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

I heard that an awaitable is an asynchronous operation. But since it is an important concept why I can't find the precise definition on MSDN?

My question is not how to write async/await. My question is to know the concept. MSDN has the concept `async/await` but no `awaitable`.

So what is an awaitable? If it is an operation, what are included?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and When to use \`async\` and \`await\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: It doesn't have the word `awaitable` in the article.

Comment: If we knew where you heard “an awaitable is an asynchronous operation” we might be able to help.

Comment: awaitable is the common English term but in .net it is known as async/await (these are the keywords).

Comment: @DourHighArch, [Here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). It can be customized so I think that has some features. Thus I want to know the precise definition.

Comment: Read the C# specification section 7.7.7

Comment: @Lee. Would you please give me the link? I can't find it by google search. There is no section 7.7.7.

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed? If so you can find the specification at `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio (Version)\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.docx`. Or you can download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all)

Comment: In this context, awaitable is class that implements certain GetAwaiter method (or even just has the right extension method with this name) - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/

Comment: Simple rule: any method whose name ends in "Async" or returns a Task.

Comment: Sort of surprised this is not a more popular question. I guess it belongs on softwareengineering.se

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I find it on [Async/Await FAQ.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/12/asyncawait-faq/)

> An “**awaitable**” is any type that exposes a GetAwaiter method which returns a valid “awaiter”. This GetAwaiter method may be an instance method (as it is in the case of Task and Task<TResult>), or it may be an extension method.
>
> An “**awaiter**” is any type returned from an awaitable’s GetAwaiter method and that conforms to a particular pattern. The awaiter must implement the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion interface, and optionally may implement the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion interface. In addition to providing an implementation of the OnCompleted method that comes from INotifyCompletion (and optionally the UnsafeOnCompleted method that comes from ICriticalNotifyCompletion), an awaiter must also provide an IsCompleted Boolean property, as well as a parameterless GetResult method. GetResult returns void if the awaitable represents a void-returning operation, or it returns a TResult if the awaitable represents a TResult-returning operation.

And this [link about awaitable and awaiter is helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065030/the-awaitable-and-awaiter-in-c-sharp-5-0-asynchronous)

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, an awaitable method or function is one that returns a `Task` or `Task<T>`. It doesn't return a data type, instead it returns a process that is asynchronous to the one that is being run at that point in time. If you had two processes, A and B, and B was only allowed to run once A was finished, B would be the awaitable method, because it would wait till A was finished, and only then would it return it's designated Task. Note that an awaitable process can also return void. This isn't the clearest of explanations but definitely helped me when I was learning.

Comment: By the Evk4's comment. awaitable is a class.Do you think so?